# custom smarty function to 'get' and 'replace'

Tags: php, html, plugins, smarty, smarty3

I am fairly new to Smarty and I am facing a little problem in writing a function for a plugin where I'd like to fetch a value from the smarty tag inserted inside any page and then I want that value to be added inside the code in the plugin file. To be precise, for example, this is going to be my Smarty tag which i'll insert inside a page:

```
{gallery link="../images/ball.png"}
```

Now what I want is that, I want the image link, which I've added inside the link="" tags, to be inserted inside the href="" and the src="" tags in the following code which is going to be inside the plugin file:

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="IMAGE LINK FROM SMARTY TAG ABOVE"><img src="IMAGE LINK FROM SMARTY TAG ABOVE" alt="" width="200" height="200" /></a>
```

So basically, if I use the following tag:

```
{gallery link="../images/car.png"}
```

I want this to be echo'd out on the page:

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="../images/car.png"><img src="../images/car.png" alt="" width="200" height="200" /></a>
```

After a lot of research, I found and read this [tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/smarty-templates-creating-smarty-custom-functions/) at last and I've learned how to create a Smarty Plugin but I am not sure how to write the correct function in order to achieve the functionality which I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly, it would be something like this (not tested):

function.gallery.php in your plugin folder

```
function smarty_function_gallery($params, $template)
{
    if (empty($params['link'])) {
        trigger_error("gallery: missing 'link' parameter",E_USER_WARNING);
        return;
    } else {
        $link = $params['link'];
    }

   return '<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="'.$link.'"><img src="'.$link.'" alt="" width="200" height="200" /></a>';
}
```

although I think it's a too specific piece of html to make a plugin just for that

Comment: This works perfectly with respect to the sort of functionality which I wanted to achieve, thanks a lot!